# Oracle автоматическое увеличение tablespace

Tags: oracle

Есть ли в 11g функция автоматического увеличения размера tablespace посредством добавления нового файла? Или все же нужно писать какую-то хранимку для этого, может у кого-то есть примеры?

Answer (score 1):

Штатного механизма, насколько я знаю, нет. 
Теоретически, можно написать скрипт, который будет по крону проверять заполнение табличных пространств и добавлять датафайлы по шаблону - но это костыль, использовать такой механизм на продакшене я бы не советовал. Стандартный путь - использование ASM(Automatic Storage Management).

Вот статья по установке и настройке:[Установка СУБД ORACLE 11gR2 на отдельно стоящий сервер под управлением ОС ORACLE Linux 6](http://habrahabr.ru/post/172513/)